# ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object' from partially initialized module 'keras.saving.legacy.serialization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I have a probleme with my code and I need help to solve it. I have tensorflow version 2.12.0.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

(train_image, train_labels), (test_image, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

And I have :

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object' from partially initialized module 'keras.saving.legacy.serialization' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/jude/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/legacy/serialization.py)
```

What is this and how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(train_image, train_labels), (test_image, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```